# I need a running timer and checker

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to create a function/alg that executes a script depending on the time. 
This won't work with PHP's 'sleep' function (I've nested loops with headers and tried).

here is the logic I am seeking to accomplish:

```
$time= time(); // checks time

if($time == 3'o'clock) { 
    do_something(); 
} else {
    check_time(); 
    and_keep_counting();
}
```

I need a continous clock ticking | which can run in the background
 at the same time, continous checking of the clock. 
 I may have to go jquery?

Comment: Seriously improve the language you use, too slangy

Comment: You also need to not use profane words; I had to [edit out](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44220851/2) a lot of stuff. Language as such could get flagged as rude/offensive.

Comment: I hope you've read and understood that ^

Comment: The pending edit https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16251375 to remove the javascript/jquery tags, should be declined since the tags are relevant to answers given.

Answer (score 1):

This will not be very efficient, but will do the trick:

```js
(function time(){
  var t = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
  console.log(t);
  if(t === "3:00:00 PM"){
    // Do whatever you need to here
    runStuff();
  }
  
  // Call the function again in 59 seconds
  setTimeout(time, 59000);
}());

function runStuff(){
  alert("Time's Up!");
}
```

Comment: THanx Scotty! -All I needed was a push

Comment: @ScottMarcus Now it's Scotty. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but you can do something like this with JavaScript...

`var date = new Date();` which creates a date-time object

`var hours = date.getHours();` which gets the hours in "military time" format, meaning 1 is 1:00AM and 13 is 1:00PM

If you want to check if it's three o'clock, you can do

```
if (hours == 15) {
  someFunction();
} else {
  doSomeOtherFunction();
}
```